# How to create encodable request in swift,when my request is present in Json?

Tags: json, swift, encodable

I want create encodable struct request for the following JSON

```
{"Symbols":[{"Name":"AAS1"},{"Name":"ASSD"}],"NoOfSymbols":2,"msgtype":15}
```

I tried to create but getting error.Type 'SymbolName' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'.Given my tried struct.

```
 struct RequestData:Encodable{
  let Symbols:[SymbolName]
  let NoOfSymbols:Int
  let msgtype: Int
 }

  struct SymbolName:Encodable{
  let Name : [String:Any]
 }
```

Comment: Try `let Name : String` instead of `let Name : [String:Any]`.

Comment: but I need array of dictionaries to be encoded@onegray

Comment: You can't use `Any` when working with `Codable`. Please describe your json, are the keys fixed or not, are the optional etc? If you want to create custom type(s) for this json you must know how it is defined in detail.

Comment: And I forgot to mention, that is not even valid JSON which makes it even more unclear what you want.

Comment: copy your json data into https://app.quicktype.io/ it will generate your structs for you.

Comment: what's unclear about `I want create encodable struct request for the following JSON`? Giving some code that the OP has tried, together with the error?

Answer (score 3):

using https://app.quicktype.io/, you get:

```
struct RequestData: Codable {
    let symbols: [Symbol]
    let noOfSymbols, msgtype: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbols = "Symbols"
        case noOfSymbols = "NoOfSymbols"
        case msgtype
    }
}

struct Symbol: Codable {
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
    }
}
```

and you can decode it like this:

```
 let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(RequestData.self, from: data)
 print("\n---> response: \(response)")
```

Similarly for encoding, such as:

```
let testData = RequestData(symbols: [Symbol(name: "AAS1"),Symbol(name: "ASSD")], noOfSymbols: 2, msgtype: 15)
let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(testData)
print(String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)
```

Comment: @RonakPatel How do you know this is a perfect answer when OP is so vague in their description. Please enlighten us.

Answer (score 1):

`Any` cannot conform to `Encodable` hence the error. But it seems you don´t need `SymbolName` at all. Try:

```
struct RequestData:Encodable{
    let Symbols:[[String:String]]
    let NoOfSymbols:Int
    let msgtype: Int
}
```

This will create the appropriate JSON (array of dictionaries):

```
{"Symbols":[{"Name":"AAS1"},{"Name":"ASSD"}],"NoOfSymbols":2,"msgtype":15}
```

Comment: You can add create a class for Symbol ```let symbols: [Symbol]``` and use it.

Comment: @RonakPatel I am aware of that but, OP stated: `but I need array of dictionaries to be encoded`. And this does exactly that. I don´t know what they "need" or "not need". BTW. there allready is an answer focusing on what OP shoud do.